# Number of real solutions $2\cos(\frac{x^2+x}{2})=2^x+2^{-x} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

The number of real solutions of $2\cos(\frac{x^2+x}{2})=2^x+2^{-x} $  is

(1) 0

(2) 1

(3) 2

(4) infinitely many .

My work :

$$
1\geq \cos\left(\frac{x^2+x}{2}\right)=\frac{2^x+2^{-x} }{2}\geq 1 
\qquad \text{by (AM-GM).}
$$

So $\frac{x^2+x}{2}=2n\pi$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ . Now discriminant $=1+2n\pi$  is always positive for $n\geq0$  . But the equation is a quadratic so it has only two solution . Hence the answer must be **2** .

PS: I'm aware that the this problem is already on the site but i posted as there were no complete solution .

Comment: No there is only one solution why dont you see their graphs

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266973/cosy-x-frac1x-possible-for-any-values-of-y/2267090#2267090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inequality implies to get a solution you must have
$$
2^x + 2^{-x} = 2
$$
which only happens when $2^x=1$, so there is only one solution.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is 1. You wrote that it should be definitely $2^x + 2^{-x} = 2$. Let $y = 2^x$, so we are intereseted in $y^2 - 2y + 1 = (y - 1)^2 = 0$. The only solution comes when $y = 1$ or $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$-2\leq 2\cos(\frac {x^2+x}{2})\leq 2$$

$$2^x+2^{-x}\geq 2$$

the root must satisfy

$$2^x+2^{-x}=2$$ which gives $x=0$.
the unique root.